# How to append a matrix to a new line in a file in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a 10x1 **matrix** of integer values in matlab, how do I write this to a **line** **text** **file**?
I am in a loop and want to **append** more than 500 such matrices, **each on a new line.**

```
fileID = fopen('exp.txt','a');

[r,c] = size(newFinalTree);
for i=1:r
    j=1;
    val=newFinalTree(i,j);
    while val~=0
       temp=reprVectors(val,:); %%%write this matrix to the file
       fprintf(fileID,temp); %%%this line produces error saying invalid format
       j=j+1;
       val=newFinalTree(i,j);
    end    
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Also what is the best way to write such a matrix so that reading the text file from a c code will be easy?

Comment: What does reprVectors return? I think that second argument of fprintf must be a string. You can put an integer in like this: fprintf(fileID, "int 1 is %d and int 2 is %d", myInt1, myInt2); So that %d in the string is a place for an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to concatenate your matrices into a `500x10` matrix and then use `dlmwrite`.

```
input=randi(100,500,10);

dlmwrite(outputFilename,input)
```

This is much less error prone than writing it yourself and it's also much faster.

If the format doesn't suit you `dlmwrite` has the possibility to change the delimiter.

Another advantage of `dlmwrite` compared to `fprintf` is that `dlmwrite` automatically selects the correct formatting for your input data.

Answer (score 0):

if reprVectors() is outputting that 10x1 you're talking about then try this small change:

```
fprintf(fileID, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store true matrices, `mat2str(...)` is your friend. You could replace:

```
fprintf(fileID,temp); %%%this line produces error saying invalid format
```

with:

```
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n',mat2str(temp))
```

or, if you want the line in your text file to be temp = (some matrix):

```
fprintf(fileID,'temp = %s\n',mat2str(temp));
```

Reading them in C should be easy, using fscanf(...) and keeping in mind that the matrix delimiters are `[]`, the line delimiters are `;` and the column delimiters are spaces.